# ColdFusion Query of Queries Encountered UPDATE

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to convert a cftag query into a cfscript query.

Here is the cftag version:

```
    <cfquery name="local.qUpdateCRDRMemo" datasource="#Application.dsn.orionTesting#">
UPDATE is_data.crdr_memo
                SET
                    ps_speed_type = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#local.valid.operatingUnit#";,
                    ps_account_no = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#local.valid.account#";,
                    ps_class = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#local.valid.class#";,
                    requested_by = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC" value="#local.requestorId#" null="#utils.isNull(local.requestorId)#";,
                    updated_by = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#utils.getUserInfo()#";
                WHERE crdr_memo_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_NUMERIC" value="#local.adjustment#" null="#utils.isNull(local.adjustment)#";
            </cfquery>
```

And this is the cfscript

```
<cfscript>
local.qUpdateCRDRMemo = queryExecute(
                "UPDATE is_data.crdr_memo
                SET
                    ps_speed_type = [local].valid.operatingUnit,
                    ps_account_no = [local].valid.account,
                    ps_class = [local].valid.class,
                    requested_by = [local].requestorId,
                    updated_by = utils.getUserInfo()
                WHERE crdr_memo_id = [local].adjustment",
                {},
                {dbtype="query"}
                );
</cfscript>
```

I'm getting the error: java.sql.SQLException: 
**Query Of Queries syntax error.**
Encountered "UPDATE.

To my understanding it sees UPDATE and thinks it is trying to be both ColdFusion and SQL, but why is that the case. I feel that I am missing something super simple but just cannot see it.

Comment: you pass `dbtype="query"`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Thanks, I figured out why that is causing the error, but what should it be?

Comment: This should be the datasource `{datasource=Application.dsn.orionTesting}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query a database with tags:

```
<cfquery name="local.qUpdateCRDRMemo" datasource="#Application.dsn.orionTesting#">
    SQL HERE
</cfquery>
```

To query a database with script:

```
var myQuery = new Query(datasource="#Application.dsn.orionTesting#", sql="
    SQL HERE
");
var myResult = myQuery.execute().getResult();
```

To run a Query of Queries (QoQ) on an existing query with tags:

```
<cfquery name="local.qUpdateCRDRMemo" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM existingQueryName
</cfquery>
```

To run a Query of Queries on an existing query in script:

```
var myQuery = new Query(dbtype="query", QoQSrcTable="#existingQueryName#", sql="
    SELECT * FROM QoQsrcTable
");
var myResult = myQuery.execute().getResult();
```

To run a Query of Queries on an existing query in script, using queryService:

```
var myQuery = new Query();
var sql = "SELECT * FROM QoQsrcTable";
// note that for queryService, you need to use the existing query VARIABLE, not its name
var myResult = queryService.execute(dbtype="query",
    qoqSrcTable=existingQueryVariable, sql=sql).getResult();
```

There are different syntaxes you can do but this is typically how I do it. The answer to your question is, your script and tag "versions" are not doing the same thing. The [`dbtype` attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html) indicates if the query will be running against an external datasource or a local query. Your tags example is hitting an external datasource. Your script example is trying to run against a local query.

[Query of Queries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html) is pretty powerful so if you don't know about it I'd read up on it as it will shed some light as to what is happening and why it isn't working as expected.

The simple answer though is to remove `dbtype="query"` and add the datasource to your script version.

```
   ... WHERE crdr_memo_id = [local].adjustment"
   , {}
   , {datasource="#Application.dsn.orionTesting#"}
 );
```

Comment: Good explanation. Might also add an example using [queryExecute()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryexecute.html). The new core function has some improvements over the cfc based `new Query()`.

Comment: Is that in cf2016? I'm still on 10.

Comment: If you want to suggest an edit with the new syntax I'll accept it to make the answer thorough. I figure this should get me what he needs though.

Comment: If I have time later, I might. Only mentioned it because `queryExecute` is used in OP, but the syntax is almost identical. So the above looks pretty good as written.